# How to get href using jsoup

Tags: java, recursion, jsoup

I have some url. I want to get all href's from the html url is pointing to and all href from all gotten hrefs(recursively). The point is I want to set depth of that "recursion"
For example, if depth = 1, I need only href's from the HTML. If depth = 2, I need hrefs from HTML(that make suppose list1) and hrefs from each of href from list1 and so on

Here is what I have using jsoup:

```
import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Parser {
    private final static String FILE_PATH = "src/main/resources/href.txt";
    private List<String> result;

    private int currentDepth;
    private int maxDepth;

    public Parser(int maxDepth) {
        result = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.maxDepth = maxDepth;
    }

    public void parseURL(String url) throws IOException {
        url = url.toLowerCase();
        if (!result.contains(url)) {
            Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(url);
            Document document = connection.get();
            Elements links = document.select("a[href]");
            for (Element link : links) {
                String href = link.attr("href");
                result.add(href);
                parseURL(link.absUrl("href"));
                currentDepth++;
                if (currentDepth == maxDepth)
                    return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How should I fix recursion condition to make it right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the depth first before calling the recursive function.

```
if (currentDepth >= maxDepth){
    // do nothing
}else{
    parseURL(...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public void parseURL(String url) throws IOException {
    url = url.toLowerCase();
    if (!result.contains(url)) {
        Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(url);
        Document document = connection.get();
        Elements links = document.getElementsByAttribute("href");
       // Elements links = document.select("a[href]");
        for (Element link : links) {
            String href = link.attr("href");
            result.add(href);
            parseURL(link.absUrl("href"));
            currentDepth++;
            if (currentDepth == maxDepth)
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

You can try this in your code, you can get all Elements from method `getElementsByAttribute(String attribute)` which have specified attribute